# Javadoc and linking to a file on a UNC Path

Tags: java, url, javadoc

Might sound crazy, but I was wanting to link some javadoc documentation to a file that exists on the network.  This is accessed from a standard UNC path.

I was wanting to link using something like as follows:

```
/**
 * This class does something in accordance with some external spec.
 * <br/><br/>
 * This spec can be found 
 * <a target="_blank" href="file://S:\Projects\Some%20Folder\Documents\External%20documents\Some%20File.pdf">here</a>.<br/>
 * And <a href="file://S:\Projects\Some Folder\Documents\External documents\Some File.pdf">here</a>
 * @author Meeeeee 
 */
public class SomeClass {
    // blah...
}
```

The link appears in the Javadoc (in Netbeans) but clicking it does not do anything.  I can link to external web pages no problem.  I have tried 2 approaches about using standard URL encoded string and unencoded string URL.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Andez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In href use it like below:
If file is in some server or some other system in LAN

```
 <a href="file:////<filelocation server or ip address>/folder/filename.xlsx">Click</a>
```

If the file is in local system

```
<a href="C:\folder\filename.xls" >click</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Anshu.  I had my slashes the wrong way.  I can load XML files from the link but not PDF - it shows as bytes.  I guess Netbeans does not handle it.